# Find all running scripts under a directory

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a bunch of shell scripts under the 'abc' directory (some of them are nested deep). There could be 100 shell scripts under it. I want to find which shell scripts that are currently running.

I can get the list of scripts with the below command

```
find abc -name "*.sh" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

When I want to find out if an individual script is running or not, I would use

```
ps aux | grep "[t]emp.sh"
```

I am not sure how to combine the above 2 commands to achieve what I want without writing a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [*process substitution* (bash)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection):

```
grep -f <(find . -name "*.sh" -printf "%f\n") <(ps aux)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method:

```
ps aux | grep \`find . -name "*.sh"\`
```

A more literal 'join' of the two commands - using the backquote (**`**) char to enclose the part that is executed first. The output from the command enclosed in the backquotes is fed into the input of the first command.